# Stop observed objects from notifying when value is set programmatically

Tags: android, android-livedata

I would like to temporarily stop a LiveData object from notifying changes without removing the Observer Object when a value is changed programmatically and receive, instead, notifications when the user changes the live data object. Is there a way to switch on/off notifications for a LiveData object keeping the observer object ?

Answer (score 1):

A LiveData has no such configuration.  Instead, you can toggle something inside your observer that tells it whether or not to act on an update from the LiveData.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `MediatorLiveData` that implements this behavior.

Idea is to hold whatever value is emitted by source livedata in temporary field before setting it as its own value (and triggering the observers):

```
class SuppressableLiveData<T>(source: LiveData<T>) : MediatorLiveData<T>() {
    private var hasSuppressedValue = false
    private var suppressedValue: T? = null
    var isSuppressed = false
        set(value) {
            field = value
            if (!value) consumeSuppressedValue()
        }

    init {
        addSource(source) { newValue ->
            if (isSuppressed) {
                hasSuppressedValue = true
                suppressedValue = newValue
            } else {
                value = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    // even when suppressed return last update emitted from source
    override fun getValue(): T? {
        return if (hasSuppressedValue) suppressedValue else super.getValue()
    }

    // undo suppression when there are no active observers
    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        consumeSuppressedValue()
    }

    private fun consumeSuppressedValue() {
        if (hasSuppressedValue) {
            value = suppressedValue
            suppressedValue = null
            hasSuppressedValue = false
        }
    }
}
```

After setting `isSuppressed = true` it will not emit any updates from `source` livedata until it's set back to `false`.